# Changing the color of myself

Tags: netlogo

I have the following code where I ask some agents to die:

```
breed [ readers reader ]
breed [ pallets pallet ]
breed [ trucks truck ]

readers-own [ 
  truck-being-served 
  pallet-being-served ]

to complete-service [ ?reader ]
  ask ?reader [
      ask pallet-being-served [ die ]
      set pallet-being-served nobody
      ask truck-being-served [
        if not any? pallets-in-truck [ 
          ask self [ die ]
          ask myself [
            set truck-being-served nobody
            set color green
            set next-completion-time 0
          ]
        ]
      ]
  ] 
end
```

Where `pallet-being-served` and `truck-being-served` are pallets and truck agents.
The problem is that the inner `ask myself [...` it seems not working, bacause the color of the `?reader` agent does not change to green. Here I am not sure if I am referring to `?reader` or to `truck-being-served` agent which I have just killed. I would like to change the color to green. Is `ask myself [ ...` referring to the reader agent?

Regards.

Comment: If you are unsure what turtle you are referring to (presumably with the `self` statement) - the easiest way to debug this is to use a `print` statement in the `ask self` block of code.

Comment: `ask self` is _never_ appropriate to write in NetLogo. You can _always_ replace `ask self [ foo ]` with just `foo`, they always mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking a dead turtle to do something has no effect.  Also, please provide a minimal runnable example that illustrates your problem.

```
globals [next-completion-time]
breed [ readers reader ]
breed [ pallets pallet ]
breed [ trucks truck ]

readers-own [ 
  truck-being-served 
  pallet-being-served ]

trucks-own [pallets-in-truck]

to setup
  ca
  create-readers 1
  create-trucks 1
  create-pallets 1
  ask reader 0 [set truck-being-served truck 1]
  ask truck 1 [set pallets-in-truck pallets]
  ask reader 0 [set pallet-being-served one-of [pallets-in-truck] of truck 1]
end

to complete-service ;reader proc
  ask pallet-being-served [ die ]
  ask truck-being-served [
    if not any? pallets-in-truck [  
      ask myself [
        set color green
        set next-completion-time 0
      ]
      die
    ]
  ]
end

to test
  setup
  ask reader 0 [complete-service]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I think that that is my error. I ask myself and probably I am referring to `truck-being-served`. I would like to change the color of the reader agent, but inside the `ask truck-being-served [...`. After a second look I think that I understand your solution. Thanks you very much, you are right.